# Remote Desktop Services status is stopped

Tags: windows, azure, azure-virtual-machine, virtual-desktop

can anyone help me to solve this issue? It says that the Remote Desktop Management and the Remote Desktop Connection Broker status are stopped. Please see image below for more details.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Resolve windows server RDP service issues by following the steps:**

> Note: **Remote Desktop Management** and the **Remote Desktop Connection Broker** status are stopped, if you disable Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.0 when you configure security settings on windows server

**Install Remote Desktop Service without Remote Desktop Connection Broker**

[image]

**Enable TLS 1.0 on Windows Server**

Open **Run** type **regedit**- and navigate to below path

**HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols**

[image]

Install &configure a high availability connection broker deployment that uses single SQL Server.

If still same error, Upgrade the computers that run the RDS services to Windows Server 2019.

Change the Service Log on Account to Network Service, like below.

[image]

As I followed same steps  **Remote Desktop Service** running without any issue.

[image]

Reference: [RDS Connection Broker or RDMS fails after you disable TLS 1.0 in Windows Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/rds-connection-broker-or-rdms-fails-caused-by-disabled-tls-10)